# How to get my python application to wait for a certain subprocess before continuing

Tags: python, process, ssh, fork, subprocess

I'm spawning an `ssh` process in my python script like this:

```
env = {'SSH_ASKPASS':'/home/max/repo/vssh/vssh/vssh.py', 'DISPLAY':':123'}
for x in sessions:
    current_session = Popen(["ssh", x.address],
                            stdin=PIPE,
                            stdout=PIPE,
                            stderr=None,
                            shell=False,
                            env=env,
                            preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

The problem is my script starts the subprocess, then keeps on going. `ssh` requires a password to be given to it, which is what I'm trying to redirect to the STDOUT/STDIN of my script. Except that by the time it asks for my password, my script is done.

How can I make my script stop until I enter the password and successfully set up a connection via `ssh`?

Comment: Isn't this the sort of thing fabric is for? http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.0/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's *really* reading from stdin, then you can use the [communicate method](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess#subprocess.Popen.communicate). But password prompts often bypass stdin and communicate with the controlling terminal, in which case you need something like [pexpect](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/).

You might want to look into SSH modules for Python, which should be simpler and more robust than managing a subprocess.

Comment: Would I be able to send to the STDIN of the controlling terminal instead?

Comment: Using pexpect, yes. Though I don't think it's called stdin for a terminal.